# Multithreading in GCP Compute Engine

Tags: python, multithreading, google-cloud-platform

I have a Python job that runs on 16 threads. If I execute it on my local machine it works just fine. On a Compute Engine VM instance, however, it shows a strange behaviour: most of the threads completes, but 1-3 of them (depending on the run) just hangs at a random moment.

Those threads don't share data with each other, so I excluded a deadlock kind of problem or other code bugs.

What is noticed is that if I run `lscpu` on the VM, this is the output:

```
Architecture:        x86_64

CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit

Byte Order:          Little Endian

CPU(s):              8

On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7

Thread(s) per core:  2

Core(s) per socket:  4

Socket(s):           1

NUMA node(s):        1

Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel

CPU family:          6

Model:               79

Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz

Stepping:            0

CPU MHz:             2200.232

BogoMIPS:            4400.46

Hypervisor vendor:   KVM

Virtualization type: full

L1d cache:           32K

L1i cache:           32K

L2 cache:            256K

L3 cache:            56320K

NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-7

Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap xsaveopt arat md_clear arch_capabilities
```

Since the machine is configured with 8vcpu (4 core with 2 threads per core), is it possible that just doesen't support running a multithreading script with 16 threads? That's quite confusing for me, considering that on a normal machine multithreading in Python is not related to any hardware configuration. Am I on the right track? Do I need to upgrade the instance or this can't be related?

Thanks in advance for any hint...

Comment: What do you mean by "just hangs"? A thread is either running, or terminated. If it's still running but is not making progress, your first step should be to find out the exact line of code where it's currently at.

Comment: What I mean is the thread is still running, but not doing anything (cpu at 0%)

Comment: It's always not doing anything _somewhere_. Again, your first step should be to find out the exact line of code where it's currently at.

Comment: I know what the line is from the logs. But then what? I'm pretty sure is not a code bug since on local it runs without problems and also most threads completes just fine. It's a batch processing job that extracts data, split them in chunks and then process them in parallel. Each thread does the same thing.

Comment: What happens if a thread throws an unhandled exception? Try it by putting a `raise` statement right before the line where it appears to hang, then run on your local machine.